# Guzzle 6 send multipart data

Tags: php, bdd, behat, guzzle

I'd like to add some data to a Guzzle Http Request. There are file name, file content and header with authorization key.

```
$this->request = $this->client->request('POST', 'url', [
    'multipart' => [
        'name' => 'image_file',
        'contents' => fopen('http://localhost:8000/vendor/l5-swagger/images/logo_small.png', 'r'),
        'headers' =>
            ['Authorization' => 'Bearer uCMvsgyuYm0idmedWFVUx8DXsN8QzYQj82XDkUTw']
            ]]);
```

but I get error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream::addElement() must be of the type array, string
>       given, called in vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\MultipartStream.php on line 70 and defined in vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\MultipartStream.php line 79

In Guzzle 6 documentation is something like this: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart

Who knows where I made a mistake?

Comment: There are some examples here: [Creating a symfony OAuth2 API client that authenticates with password grant type](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/l4zx/creating-a-symfony-oauth2-api-client-that-authenticates-with-password-grant-type) and [Consuming symfony API with Guzzle client from another application](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/u0xf/consuming-symfony-api-with-guzzle-client-from-another-application)

Comment: Thanks, however, these tutorials are to the previous Guzzle version. I'm using latest version.

Comment: The first link uses guzzle 6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the solution. Header with access token should be outside multipart section.

```
$this->request = $this->client->request('POST', 'request_url', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer access_token'
            ],
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    'name' => 'image_file',
                    'contents' => fopen('image_file_url', 'r')
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: I did this and it still gives me the same error about the "contents" line.

Answer (score 8):

As per the docs, "The value of multipart is **an array of associative arrays**", so you need to nest one level deeper:

```
$this->request = $this->client->request('POST', 'url', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'image_file',
            'contents' => fopen('http://localhost:8000/vendor/l5-swagger/images/logo_small.png', 'r'),
            'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer uCMvsgyuYm0idmedWFVUx8DXsN8QzYQj82XDkUTw']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: @PrzemekGawłowski I don't mean you just need to format the code differently, you need to give the multipart option "an array of associative arrays". In your code you're just giving it a single associative array. Wrap some extra square brackets around it, as in my example.

Comment: You're right, my bad. So now i got this error message :-(

`Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string in features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php line 246`

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the code, but it sounds like you're missing a call to the getBody() method, e.g. echo (string) $response->getBody();

Comment: $response->getBody();

`Server error: "POST my_url" resulted in a "500 Internal Server Error" response:
      {"message":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more  (tr
uncated...)
       (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException)`

Comment: Now it just sounds like you're sending a request the server doesn't understand. We're getting quite off-topic though.

Answer (score 1):

try this
works for me

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils;

$this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://baseurl'
    ]);

$body = Utils::tryFopen($tempPath . $fileName, 'r');
$res = $this->client->request(
                 'POST',
                 'url',
                  [
                     'headers' => [
                        ...
                     ],
                     'body' => $body
                  ]
            );
```